# Marking/unmarking checkbox based on textbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes, where one of them has a textbox next to it. I cannot change the code, as it is auto-generated from our interview system.

```
<span class="mrMultipleText"><input type="checkbox"     class="mrMultiple" name="LIST10" value="12" id="12"><label for="12"><font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans Serif" color="#000000"><strong>Nyhed</strong></font></label></span><br>
<span class="mrMultipleText"><input type="checkbox" class="mrMultiple" name="LIST10" value="11" id="11"><label for="11"><font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans Serif" color="#000000"><strong>Reklame</strong></font></label></span><br>
<span class="mrMultipleText"><input type="checkbox" class="mrMultiple" name="LIST10" value="15" id="15"><label for="15"><font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans Serif" color="#000000"><strong>Reportage</strong></font></label></span><br>
<span class="mrMultipleText"><input type="checkbox" class="mrMultiple" name="LIST10" value="14" id="14"><label for="14"><font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans Serif" color="#000000"><strong>Artikel</strong></font></label></span><br>
<span class="mrMultipleText"><input type="checkbox" class="mrMultiple" name="LIST10" value="13" id="13"><label for="13"><font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans Serif" color="#000000"><strong>Information</strong></font></label></span><br>
<span class="mrMultipleText"><input type="checkbox" class="mrMultiple" name="LIST10" value="16" id="16"><label for="16"><font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans Serif" color="#000000"><strong>Andet, notér:</strong></font></label></span>&nbsp;<input class="mrEdit" type="text" name="EDIT19" size="40" value=""><br>
<span class="mrSingleText"><input type="checkbox" class="mrSingle" name="LIST10" value="17" id="17"><b><font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans Serif" color="#808080"><strong><label for="17">Ved ikke</label></strong></font></b></span><br>
```

I'm trying to do so that when our users type something in the textbox, it automatically marks the previous checkbox and if the user deletes all the text, it unmarks the checkbox. I can't seem to get it working. I've tried using value-length, a click that triggers another click and so on. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Comment: I've tried the following: if val.length >0 click the span, and when you click the span, a click on the checkbox is triggered. I've also tried using focusout to trigger a click if the val.length>0. None of which has worked. I run into problems when the if commands is parsed through multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Here's a version that only needs to know the textbox. The checkbox is found using jQuery without knowing its `id`. [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/je3aapt7/2/)

Bind an event listener to the textbox, check its `.val().length`, and then toggle the checkbox's `.prop('checked')` accordingly.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je3aapt7/).

Comment: This works perfectly. Only problem is, that the id is dynamic. Can you see a way to fetch the id and then use it in the suggested function?

Comment: @FGLWEBPOL I think I understand what you need. See the updated answer.

Comment: That is nothing less than perfect. THANK YOU!